# Code doesn't work in foreach

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error

Here is my code:

```
var divarray = document.getElementById("yui-main").getElementsByTagName("div");
var articleHTML;
var absHTML;
var keyHTML;
var bodyHTML = [];
for( var i in divarray) {
    if(divarray[i].className == "articleBody"){
        articleHTML = divarray[i];
        for( var j in articleHTML ){
            bodyHTML[i] = '';
            if(articleHTML[j].className == "issueMiniFeature"){continue;}
            if(articleHTML[j].className == "abstract"){absHTML = articleHTML[i]; continue;}
            if(articleHTML[j].className == "journalKeywords"){keyHTML = articleHTML[i]; continue;}
            bodyHTML[i] = articleHTML[i];
        }
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
```

I am using Google Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mistaking JavaScript for the functionality of PHP.  JavaScript does not have `foreach` loops.  JavaScript has `for in`, which is what you are incorrectly using and normal `for` loops.  Use a standard `for` loop when dealing with arrays.  You will need to use a `for in` loop with object literals because the index is not the simplicity of an incrementing positive integer.

In JavaScript a `for` loop has 3 parts in its argument separated by a semicolon as follows:
* start position of incrementor (optional if the variable is previous defined with 0 or a positive integer)
* end position of incrementor
* method of incrementation

In the following examples `arrayName` is value I made up for the name of an array:

```
for (; a < arrayName.length; a += 1) {
for (a = x + 1; a < arrayName.length + 3; a += 2) {
```

The `for in` loop argument has two required parts and a third part to prevent errors using an `if` condition:
* The value of an index to search for
* The name of the container in which to search
* The third part is an `if` condition

The following example will return the value supplied to the "book" index of the objectName object literal.  `objectName` is a name I made for an example object literal:

```
for ("book" in objectName) {
    if (objectName.hasProperty("book")) {
```

Answer (score 4):

The javascript `for...in` doesn't do what you would expect (which is enumerate through eleemnts in an array.

`for...in` in javascript will enumerate through the key/value pairs (or public variables) that make up the object (which isn't what you want).

You need to use a good, old fashioned `for` loop.

Comment: +1: I've run into this exact problem.  However, I opted to use jQuery's .each loop instead, since it was in a (custom) jQuery plugin used by my employer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your script:

```
Array.prototype.foreach = function (callback) {
    for (var i=0; i < this.length; i++) {
        callback(this[i]);
    }
}
```

Then you simply do this:

```
myarray.foreach(function (currentItem) {
    /*...do whatever with the currentItem...*/
});
```

Comment: The function tends to be called `each` or `map`.  Good idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a traditional for loop instead? You're not really using an associative array here ...

Answer (score 0):

That's not the right way to iterate over a collection.

You want a standard `for` loop, not a `for..in` loop

```
for( var i = 0, l = divarray.length; i < l; i++ ) {
```

There's something else, you then proceed to try to iterate over each element

```
for( var j in articleHTML ){
```

`articleHTML` at this point holds a reference to a single HTML node - not a collection or array of any sort.